# Make gnome-desktop clock larger

Tags: xfce, lock-screen, clock, fonts, gnome-screensaver

I use Xfce with gnome-screensaver. Is it possible to change the font size of the date/time in the lock screen (on the top bar) without making any changes to font sizes elsewhere? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Click the **All Settings** icon from the top left launcher.  From there, click on the **Panel** icon.  On the Display tab, you'll see a **Measurements** section.  Just increase the **Row Size (pixels)** setting to the size that you want.